# Can you work on a read-only master and a new slide in the same window?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, master

I have a program limitations question regarding PowerPoint for PC:

Imagine two slides, one a read-only master, and one a new slide, cascaded.

Now imagine that the user wants to have that master, and be able to work on the new one, but within the SAME window – not cascaded. Copying and pasting or clicking and dragging is fine, but within the SAME window. Is this possible?